# Python Geopandas Module Object Not Callable

Tags: python, plot, mapping, geopandas

i am trying to plot x,y or latitude and longitude points on a map using geopandas and I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\U321103\.spyder-py3\Plot90thPercentile_MKTest_maps.py", line 
19, in <module>
gdf = gdf(dfp, geometry=geometry)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My code looks like this:

```
from sys import exit
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import geodataframe as gdf
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import pandas as pd


dfp = pd.read_csv("\\\porfiler03\\gtdshare\\Long_Lats_90p.csv", 
delimiter=',', skiprows=0, 
low_memory=False)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(dfp['Longitude'], dfp['Latitude'])]
gdf = gdf(dfp, geometry=geometry)   

#this is a simple map that goes with geopandas
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf.plot(ax=world.plot(figsize=(10, 6)), marker='o', color='green', 
markersize=15);
exit()
```

The error i am getting is on line 19:

```
gdf = gdf(dfp, geometry=geometry)
```

The error i think might be related to the fact that something on line 19 is not "callable" and it must be "gdf" but I'm not sure how to fix this. Ultimately, i need a map with the points in my file to show up as red dots on a world map. My df "dfp" looks like this - thank you for your help!

```
   Longitude  Latitude
0    -76.124    40.853
1    -96.063    44.065
2     -3.480    43.140
3     -2.060    38.750
4     -2.420    38.880
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` class, but are importing `geopandas.geodataframe` module instead. Remember that Python is case sensitive.

```py
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame as gdf
```

Comment: thanks - but when I try "GeoDataFrame" in the import changing as you suggest, i get this error - ImportError: cannot import name 'GeoDataFrame' from 'geopandas' (unknown location) - but when i change to "geodataframe" then it does not show error.

Comment: The simple solution would be to use `gpd.GeoDataFrame` and not import it individually at all.

Comment: ok, i only use "gpd" once when I try and define the "world" variable. How would it use this in my code above? my error is before that use of "gpd" on line 19.

Comment: `gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfp, geometry=geometry)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a problem with installing "geopandas". I have removed and then re-installed this package and the error does not occur.